# Output a Sudoku board

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, grid, sudoku

Today's challenge is simple: Without taking any input, output any valid sudoku board.

In case you are unfamiliar with sudoku, [Wikipedia describes what a valid board should look like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku):

> The objective is to fill a 9×9 grid with digits so that each column, each row, and each of the nine 3×3 subgrids that compose the grid (also called "boxes", "blocks", or "regions") contains all of the digits from 1 to 9.

Now here's the thing... There are [6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960 different valid sudoku boards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-solutions-a-sudoku-puzzle-can-have). Some of them may be very difficult to compress and output in fewer bytes. Others of them may be easier. Part of this challenge is to figure out which boards will be most compressible and could be outputted in the fewest bytes.

Your submission does not necessarily have to output the same board every time. But if multiple outputs are possible, you'll have to prove that every possible output is a valid board.

You can use [this script](https://tio.run/#05ab1e#code=fMKpdnkzw7R9KTPDtMO4dnlKdnnDqn19wq7DuHZ5w6p9wq52ecOqfSnDqsW-aMKmUQ&input=MTIzNDU2Nzg5CjQ1Njc4OTEyMwo3ODkxMjM0NTYKMjMxNTY0ODk3CjU2NDg5NzIzMQo4OTcyMzE1NjQKMzEyNjQ1OTc4CjY0NTk3ODMxMgo5NzgzMTI2NDU) (thanks to Magic Octopus Urn) or [any of these answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22443/create-a-sudoku-solution-checker) to verify if a particular grid is a valid solution. It will output a `[1]` for a valid board, and anything else for an invalid board.

I'm not too picky about what format you output your answer in, as long as it's clearly 2-dimensional. For example, you could output a 9x9 matrix, nine 3x3 matrices, a string, an array of strings, an array of 9-digit integers, or nine 9-digit numbers with a separator. Outputting 81 digits in 1 dimension would not be permitted. If you would like to know about a particular output format, feel free to ask me in the comments.

As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so write the shortest answer you can come up with in the language(s) of your choosing!

Comment: Can we output three 3x9 matrices? Each row of each submatrix representing a row in the sudoku board. Like [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98y6OHOmQnFxlH//wMA)

Comment: [Related but not a dup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126930/draw-a-sudoku-board-using-line-drawing-characters). Also, if you're allowing flexible output I'm not sure that [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] applies, since that is normally for fixed outputs like exact ascii art.

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
.<LS9%D3 9
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%3CLS9%25D3+9&debug=0)

```
.<LS9%D3 9
     %D3 9     Order the range [0, ..., 8] mod 3.
  >            For each, ...
.< S9          ... Rotate the list [1, ..., 9] that many times.
```

Comment: 11: `m.<S9d%D3 9`.

Comment: Cross that out, 10: `.<LS9%D3 9`.

Comment: Might wanna update the link ([tio](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8/GJ9hS1cVYwfL/fwA))

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
l=range(1,10)
for x in l:print(l*9)[x*8/3:][:9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8e2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IoUIhM08hx6qgKDOvRCNHy1IzukLLQt/YKjbayjL2/38A)

Answer (score 9):

## T-SQL, <s>96</s> 89 bytes

Found one shorter than the trivial output!

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING('12345678912345678',0+value,9)FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9',',')
```

Extracts 9-character strings starting at different points, as defined by the in-memory table created by `STRING_SPLIT` (which is supported on SQL 2016 and later). The `0+value` was the shortest way I could do an implicit cast to integer.

Original trivial output (96 bytes):

```sql
PRINT'726493815
315728946
489651237
852147693
673985124
941362758
194836572
567214389
238579461'
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
9Rṙ%3$Þ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98y6OHOmarGKofn/f8PAA)

*And a little bit of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172475/41024)...*
-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)('s thinking?)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
r=range(9)
for i in r:print[1+(j*10/3+i)%9for j in r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPVXDUpMrLb9IIVMhM0@hyKqgKDOvJNpQWyNLy9BA31g7U1PVEiSdBZaO/f8fAA)

---

Alternatives:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
i=0;exec"print[1+(i/3+j)%9for j in range(9)];i-=8;"*9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZqaAoM68k2lBbI1PfWDtLU9UyLb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVXDUjPWOlPX1sJaScvy/38A)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
for i in range(81):print(i/9*10/3+i)%9+1,'\n'*(i%9>7),
```

```python
i=0;exec"print[1+(i/3+j)%9for j in range(9)];i+=10;"*9
```

```python
r=range(9);print[[1+(i*10/3+j)%9for j in r]for i in r]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```python
l=*range(10),
for i in b"	":print(l[i:]+l[1:i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8dWqygxLz1Vw9BAU4crLb9IIVMhM08hSYmRhZ2JlYOZjVPJqqAoM69EIyc60ypWOyfa0CozVvP/fwA)

- -3 bytes thanks to Jo King,

The elements of the byte string end up giving the numbers `[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]` which are used to permute the rotations of `[0..9]`. The `0` is removed in `l[1:i]` and there is no need for a null byte which takes two characaters (`\0`) to represent in a bytes object.

**[55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P15HK8e2KDEvPVXD0ECTKy2/SCFTITNPIUmJkYWdiZWDmY1TyaqgKDOvRCMnOtMqVjsn2iozVvP/fwA)**

```python
_,*l=range(10)
for i in b"	":print(l[i:]+l[:i])
```

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8dWqygxLz1Vw9BAU4crLb9IIVMhM08hSYmRhZ2JlYOZjVPJqqAoM69EIyc60ypWOyfa0CozVvP/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Clever, thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

Output as an array of the rows.

```javascript
_=>[...w="147258369"].map(x=>(w+w).substr(x,9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5aT0@v3FbJ0MTcyNTC2MxSKVYvN7FAo8LWTqNcu1xTr7g0qbikSKNCx1JT8791cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmgZQBAA)

Generates this:

```
472583691
583691472
691472583
725836914
836914725
914725836
258369147
369147258
147258369
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
9Rṙ`s3ZẎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98y6OHOmQnFxlEPd/X9/w8A)

```
9Rṙ`s3ZẎ
9R         Range(9) -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   `       Use the same argument twice for the dyad:
  ṙ        Rotate [1..9] each of [1..9] times.
           This gives all cyclic rotations of the list [1..9]
    s3     Split into three lists.
      Z    Zip. This puts the first row of each list of three in it's own list, 
           as well as the the second and third.
       Ẏ   Dump into a single list of nine arrays.
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 84 bytes

```
@set s=123456789
@for %%a in (0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8)do @call echo %%s:~%%a%%%%s:~,%%a%%
```

Uses @Mnemonic's output. `call` is used to interpolate the variable into the slicing operation (normally it only accepts numeric constants).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>40 32</s> 27 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{[^9+1].rotate($+=3.3)xx 9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo6zlLbMFavKL8ksSRVQ0Xb1ljPWLOiQsGy9n@ahqZebmKBhpZecWKl5n8A)

Anonymous code block that returns a 9x9 matrix. Maps each row to a different rotation of the range 1 to 9.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
8ÝΣ3%}ε9Ls._
```

-2 bytes by creating a port of [*@Mnemonic*'s Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172475/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4vDcc4uNVWvPbbX0KdaL/@9Ve2j3fwA) (Footer is added to pretty-print it. Actual result is a 9x9 matrix; feel free to remove the footer to see.)

**Explanation:**

```python
8Ý              # List in the range [0, 8]
  Σ  }          # Sort the integers `i` by
   3%           #  `i` modulo-3
      ε         # Map each value to:
       9L       #  List in the range [1, 9]
         s._    #  Rotated towards the left the value amount of times
```

---

**Original 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) solution:**

```
9Lε9LN3*N3÷+._
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufcVksfP2MtP@PD27X14v971R7a/R8A) (Footer is added to pretty-print it. Actual result is a 9x9 matrix; feel free to remove the footer to see.)

**Explanation:**

```python
9L                # Create a list of size 9
  ε               # Change each value to:
   9L             #  Create a list in the range [1, 9]
     N3*N3÷+      #  Calculate N*3 + N//3 (where N is the 0-indexed index,
                  #                        and // is integer-division)
            ._    #  Rotate that many times towards the left
```

Both answers result in the Sudoku:

```python
123456789
456789123
789123456
234567891
567891234
891234567
345678912
678912345
912345678
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>82</s> 75 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=81;i-->0;)System.out.print((i/9*10/3+i)%9+1+(i%9<1?" ":""));}
```

-7 bytes by creating a port of one of [*@TFeld*'s Python 2 answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172526/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7PCoJAEIfvPcUgCLuJ/@iSbdoT5EXoEh22VWNMV9FVCPHZt7W8zDC/Yb75Kj5xt8rfWtR8GODKUc47AJSq6EsuCkjXEWBqMQdBbmubKDPZsjNlUFyhgBQkxKAnN5nLtifmGjA@hgxdNwkYzT6DKhqvHZXX9WZJCPrRPgz8g4PUjpzQIWhH5/BigXWyLErZotmK78ZnbfDbl59DYwxJpgzmdX8Ap3896Qkix7rezBb9BQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                    // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=81;i-->0;)  //  Loop `i` in the range (81, 0]
    System.out.print(   //   Print:
     (i/9               //    (`i` integer-divided by 9,
         *10            //     then multiplied by 10,
         /3             //     then integer-divided by 3,
           +i)          //     and then we add `i`)
             %9         //    Then take modulo-9 on the sum of that above
               +1       //    And finally add 1
    +(i%9<1?            //    Then if `i` modulo-9 is 0:
            " "         //     Append a space delimiter
           :            //    Else:
            ""));}      //     Append nothing more
```

Outputs the following sudoku (space delimited instead of newlines like below):

```java
876543219
543219876
219876543
765432198
432198765
198765432
654321987
321987654
987654321
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
>:(,&|:|."{,)i.3 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/@2sNHTUaqxq9JSqdTQz9YwVjP9rcqUmZ@QrpP0HAA)

#### Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

#### How it works

```
>:(,&|:|."{,)i.3 3
             i.3 3  The 2D array X = [0 1 2;3 4 5;6 7 8]
   ,&|:|."{,        3-verb train:
   ,&|:               Transpose and flatten X to get Y = [0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8]
           ,          Flatten X to get Z = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
       |."{           Get 2D array whose rows are Z rotated Y times
>:                  Increment
```

### Fancy version, 23 bytes

```
|.&(>:i.3 3)&.>|:{;~i.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/2v01DTsrDL1jBWMNdX07Gqsqq3rgLz/mlypyRn5Cmn/AQ)

Output:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│1 2 3│4 5 6│7 8 9│
│4 5 6│7 8 9│1 2 3│
│7 8 9│1 2 3│4 5 6│
├─────┼─────┼─────┤
│2 3 1│5 6 4│8 9 7│
│5 6 4│8 9 7│2 3 1│
│8 9 7│2 3 1│5 6 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┤
│3 1 2│6 4 5│9 7 8│
│6 4 5│9 7 8│3 1 2│
│9 7 8│3 1 2│6 4 5│
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

#### How it works

```
|.&(>:i.3 3)&.>|:{;~i.3
                    i.3  Array [0 1 2]
                 {;~     Get 2D array of boxed pairs (0 0) to (2 2)
               |:        Transpose
|.&(>:i.3 3)&.>          Change each pair to a Sudoku box:
            &.>            Unbox
    >:i.3 3                2D array X = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
|.&                        Rotate this 2D array over both axes
                             e.g. 1 2|.X gives [6 4 5;9 7 8;3 1 2]
            &.>            Box again so the result looks like the above
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) & Matlab,<strike>50</strike> <strike>48</strike> 29 bytes

```matlab
mod((1:9)+['furRaghAt']',9)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Nz9FQ8PQylJTO1o9rbQoKDE9w7FEPVZdByhi@P8/AA)

*-2 thanks to Johnathon frech*

*-14 thanks to Sanchises Broadcast addition suggestion, who also pointed out the non-compatibility.*

*-5 by noticing that the vector can be written in matlab with a char string and transposition.*

Was intuitive, now not so. 
Uses broadcast summing to spread 1:9 over 9 rows, spread by values determined by the char string.

Sudoku board produced:

```matlab
 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG; nice first post.

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Nz9FI7rY1tDK0rpY2xiIzYDYEIhNgNgciI2A2BSILWJ1LDW1Df//BwA).

Comment: Of course, s could be defined in the matrix itself. I must have miscounted the bytes as well.

Comment: This is now Octave, no longer compatible with MATLAB. If you like, you can use the little chain icon at the top of Jonathan's link to copy paste the default PPCG formatting.

Comment: If you like, you can get this down to 34 bytes with broadcast addition: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Nz9FQ8PQylJTO9rY2sza0trQ2sTa3NrI2tTaIlYHKGz4/z8A "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue Sanchises, now fixed with your suggestion and improved on top.

Comment: Save one more: `(1:9)+'furRaghAt'.'`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
[[x..9]++[1..x-1]|x<-[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dca7DoMgGAbQvU/xxTjY8ENC7ybqSzgiA7FNNFUwQFOGvjv2TGcy4f1alpxDq1QSotaMKSlE4lL/UsOVpAvd6URXetCZblRrnVczW7R4ugO2T@yjR4nR2dHEf1azoRo8eIcwuS88GEMx2OKIkHc)

Comment: This is not valid. Each square contains multiple of the same number. You could do something [like this (43 bytes)](https://tio.run/##Dca7DoMgGAbQvU/xxTjY8ENC7ybqSzgiA7FNNFUwQFOGvjv2TGcy4f1alpxDq1QSotaMKSlE4lL/UsOVpAvd6URXetCZblRrnVczW7R4ugO2T@yjR4nR2dHEf1azoRo8eIcwuS88GEMx2OKIkHc "Haskell – Try It Online") instead

Comment: Thanks! I took your suggestion

Comment: @RushabhMehta I did. It was 43 bytes but I removed the `s=` since it isn't necessary

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
(a=*1..9).map{|x|p a.rotate x*3.3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyPRVstQT89SUy83saC6pqKmQCFRryi/JLEkVaFCy1jPuPb/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>16</s> 11 bytes

```
9{9╒♂ï*3/Ä╫
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9tYXRoZ29sZv//OXs54pWS4pmCw68qMy/DhOKVq/9hbv8)

Saved 5 bytes thanks to JoKing

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9tYXRoZ29sZv//OXs54pWS4pmCw68qMy/DhOKVq/9hbv8 "MathGolf – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 81 bytes

```
l=list(range(1,10))
for i in range(1,10):print(l);l=l[3+(i%3==0):]+l[:3+(i%3==0)]
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8c2J7O4RKMoMS89VcNQx9BAU5MrLb9IIVMhM08BSdSqoCgzr0QjR9MaqCPaWFsjU9XY1hYoHqudE22F4Mf@/w8A)

I like having 81 bytes, but after some optimizing :(

## Python 2 - <s>75 68 59</s> 58 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to @DLosc*

*-9 bytes thanks to @Mnemonic*

*-1 byte thanks to @JoKing*

```
l=range(1,10)
for i in l:print l;j=i%3<1;l=l[3+j:]+l[:3+j]
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8e2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IIVMhM08hx6qgKDOvRCHHOss2U9XYxtA6xzYn2lg7yypWOyfaCsiI/f8fAA)

Comment: *81 bytes* Perfect score! :D

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I was considering making it shorter by doing `r=range(1,10)` but I couldn't ruin the beauty

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8c2WqsoMS89VcNQx9BAM5YrLb9IIVMhM08hx6qgKDOvRCNH0zrHNifaWFsjU9XY1tZA0ypWOyfaCsGP/f8fAA) ;)

Comment: @DLosc Ooh clever reuse of `l`

Comment: If you don't mind Python 2, you can take the parens out of the print and remove the list packing.

Comment: How exactly do you remove the list packing?

Comment: `range` already returns a list in Python 2.  [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8e2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IIVMhM08hx6qgKDOvRCHHOss2U9XY1tbAOsc2J9pYO8sqVjsn2grIiP3/HwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mnemonic Oh right, I forgot, xrange is the generator in Python 2

Answer (score 2):

Huge Thanks to @Shaggy!

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
t=>[...s='123456789'].map(e=>s.slice(t=e*3.3%9)+s.slice(0,t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/E1i5aT0@v2Fbd0MjYxNTM3MJSPVYvN7FAI9XWrlivOCczOVWjxDZVy1jPWNVSUxsmZKBToqn5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI01DU5PrPwA)

Comment: A quick bit of golfing gets this down to [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5aT0@vylbJ0MjYxNTM3MJSKVYvN7FAI9XWrkqvOCczOVWjxDZVy1jPWNVSx1JTGyZooFOiqfk/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTUNTLys/My8hJi9Bk@s/AA).

Comment: Sorry, [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5aT0@vylbJ0MjYxNTM3MJSKVYvN7FAI9XWrkqvOCczOVWjxDZVy1jPWNVSUxsmZKBToqn5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI01DUy8rPzMvISYvQZPrPwA); missed a stupidly obvious golf!

Answer (score 2):

[**R**](https://www.r-project.org/)**, 54 bytes**

```
x=1:9;for(y in(x*3)%%10)print(c(x[-(1:y)],x[(1:y)]))
```

**Output:**

```
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
[1] 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
[1] 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
[1] 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
[1] 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
[1] 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8LW0MrSOi2/SKNSITNPo0LLWFNV1dBAs6AoM69EI1mjIlpXw9CqUjNWpyIawtDU/M/1HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 51 bytes

```python
r='147258369';print([(r*4)[int(i):][:9]for i in r])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
r='147258369'
for i in r:print(r*4)[int(i):][:9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8hW3dDE3MjUwtjMUp0rLb9IIVMhM0@hyKqgKDOvRKNIy0QzGsTI1LSKjbayjP3/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
◂ｊ３［«３［Ｔ３［«
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNUMyJXVGRjRBJXVGRjEzJXVGRjNCJUFCJXVGRjEzJXVGRjNCJXVGRjM0JXVGRjEzJXVGRjNCJUFC,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｅ⁹⭆⁹⊕﹪⁺÷×χι³λ⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDUkchuATIS4dyPPOSi1JzU/NKUlM0fPNTSnPyNQJySos1PPNKXDLLMlNSNUIyc1OLNQwNdBQyNXUUjIE4B4gtNUHA@v///7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses @Mnemonic's output. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⁹              Map over 9 rows
  ⭆⁹            Map over 9 columns and join
          ι     Current row
         χ      Predefined variable 10
        ×       Multiply
       ÷   ³    Integer divide by 3
            λ   Current column
      ⁺         Add
     ﹪       ⁹  Modulo 9
    ⊕           Increment
                Implicitly print each row on its own line
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
9õ ñu3
£éX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=OfUg8XUzCqPpWA==&input=LVI=) or [verify the output](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5tDKskrjw1tqNYHE4R1llV5llYdX1dYeWgfiAFmH1oEpzcOrju7LOLQs8P9/I1MLYzNLQxNzLiCGcLggAkAOlwWMyWUOU8hlCVPIBdNqxAXTasgF02oMAA)

---

### Explanation

```
9õ         :Range [1,9]
   ñ       :Sort by
    u3     :  Mod 3 of each
\n         :Assign to variable U
£          :Map each X
 éX        :  U rotated right by X
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 65 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=0;i<81;)printf("%d%c",(i/9*10/3+i)%9+1,i++%9>7?10:9);}
```

The function is now able to be reused

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDoIwEAXQtT0FwTSZsSg0LrQW8SyktfgTbA2iG8LZq2//3N6NfRxyDgReQpoI18aiPWvLrwlxDlRKL11ZEWqz0019VGBplK6glDTd6aabi2G75i2iGz/@XrTv2SMdHp34/@LZI9I3wfMiNoHYijX/AA)

Comment: Instead of printing a NUL byte to seperate your digits, you could use a tab character at the same byte count.

Comment: "Your submission does not necessarily have to output the same board every time. But if multiple outputs are possible, you'll have to prove that every possible output is a valid board." It does not say that multiple outputs are needed. @ceilingcat

Comment: @Logern The rule in question is that [function submissions have to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/39242). It’s fine if it `f(); f()` outputs the same board twice, but not if the second call doesn’t work at all.

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEAXQtZyiqSGZkWohbkSqnqUBsT@pYGp10/Ts6Ns/v/djnx6lRAIvMU@Ei3boTsbxa0KaI9UySF83hNbujG6PCiytMo1SkPZmz0azW8sWyY@fcK@69xyQD8NV/Hf17JHomxF4EZtI7MRafg "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: 61 bytes, incorporating suggestions from @JoKing `f(i){for(i=81;i--;)printf("%d%c",(i/9*10/3+i)%9+1,i%9?9:10);}`

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 16 bytes

```
1+9!(<9#!3)+\:!9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/99Q21JRw8ZSWdFYUzvGStHy/38A)

First answer in ngn/k, done with a big help from the man himself, @ngn.

#### How:

```
1+9!(<9#!3)+\:!9 // Anonymous fn
              !9 // Range [0..8]
    (     )+\:   // Sum (+) that range with each left (\:) argument
        !3       // Range [0..2]
      9#         // Reshaped (#) to 9 elements: (0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2)
     <           // Grade up
  9!             // Modulo 9
1+               // plus 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṠmṙÖ%3ḣ9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9odXNr///huaBt4bmZw5YlM@G4ozn//w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 344 bytes

```
{iiiii}icicicicicicic{d}iicic{dddd}c{iiii}iiiicicicic{d}iicicicicic{dddd}dddc{iiiii}dddc{d}iicicicicicicicic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}cicicicicicicic{d}iic{dddd}ic{iiii}iiicicicicic{d}iicicicic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiiiicic{d}iicicicicicicic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}dcicicicicicicicic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iicicicicicic{d}iicicic{dddd}dc{iiii}iiiiicicic{d}iicicicicicic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoAgDARf5KPMVuOeOZK@vQIFRWwJAcJkZ@XY5WS6NrPMOkrMK4vSzzKK7Ai5/o9XpcpGD2vXD7KAD6uIxM7x9SISj7SpHv/lFm@HBWE3abKRh8jbs2YpIqvZDQ)